# to many OPEN_AUTH_FAILURE in my stackdriver

Tags: actions-on-google

Last week I get a email from google saying that my project has a high error rate.

I checked the stackdriver log and foud a lot of the same errors "OPEN_AUTH_FAILURE"

```
019-01-24 05:50:24.009 GMT
requestId 11208018970435955658 failed with code: OPEN_AUTH_FAILURE
全部展开 | 全部收起 {
 insertId:  "1e1u2yf5abv81"   
 logName:  "projects/ankuoo-50c50/logs/actions.googleapis.com%2Factions"   
 receiveTimestamp:  "2019-01-24T05:50:24.045620573Z"   
 resource: {
  labels: {
   action_id:  "SMART_HOME_QUERY"     
   project_id:  "ankuoo-50c50"     
   version_id:  ""     
  }
  type:  "assistant_action"    
 }
 severity:  "ERROR"   
 textPayload:  "requestId 11208018970435955658 failed with code: OPEN_AUTH_FAILURE"   
 timestamp:  "2019-01-24T05:50:24.009362763Z"   
}
2019-01-24 05:50:24.009 GMT
requestId 11208018970435955658: Agent responded empty JSON.
全部展开 | 全部收起 {
 insertId:  "1e1u2yf5abv82"   
 logName:  "projects/ankuoo-50c50/logs/actions.googleapis.com%2Factions"   
 receiveTimestamp:  "2019-01-24T05:50:24.045620573Z"   
 resource: {
  labels: {
   action_id:  "SMART_HOME_QUERY"     
   project_id:  "ankuoo-50c50"     
   version_id:  ""     
  }
  type:  "assistant_action"    
 }
 severity:  "ERROR"   
 textPayload:  "requestId 11208018970435955658: Agent responded empty JSON."   
 timestamp:  "2019-01-24T05:50:24.009367337Z"   
}
```

At first I thought it has a bug in my fulfillment, but I didn't find any request record in my tomcat log file or even nginx access log

```
54.198.206.193 [24/Jan/2019:05:50:22 +0000] "POST /alexa/devices HTTP/1.1" 200 134 "-" "python-requests/2.7.0 CPython/2.7.12 Linux/4.14.88-72.76.amzn1.x86_64"
72.21.217.66 [24/Jan/2019:05:50:23 +0000] "POST /oauth2/access_token HTTP/1.1" 200 179 "-" "Apache-HttpClient/4.5.x (Java/1.8.0_192)"
54.198.206.193 [24/Jan/2019:05:50:23 +0000] "POST /alexa/devices HTTP/1.1" 200 337 "-" "python-requests/2.7.0 CPython/2.7.12 Linux/4.14.88-72.76.amzn1.x86_64"
54.198.206.193 [24/Jan/2019:05:50:24 +0000] "POST /alexa/power HTTP/1.1" 200 27 "-" "python-requests/2.7.0 CPython/2.7.12 Linux/4.14.88-72.76.amzn1.x86_64"
72.21.217.83 [24/Jan/2019:05:50:27 +0000] "POST /oauth2/access_token HTTP/1.1" 200 179 "-" "Apache-HttpClient/4.5.x (Java/1.8.0_192)"
```

the path begin with "alexa" is API for amazon alexa, so it seems like my service did not receive a request from Google. I have no idea how to solve this problem.

Comment: The first error appears to be related to auth, so you should try to verify that auth works successfully. The second seems to be an issue with returning an empty response, so you may want to do additional logging to verify that you're processing requests and responses correctly.

Comment: @NickFelker but according to the nginx log I provided, my service did not receive any request from Google.Is it possible that Google sent the request to somewhere else?

Comment: You should probably check your authentication system right now

Comment: @NickFelker I use google Oauth2 playground to test my auth server. The response is HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 26 Jan 2019 03:03:28 GMT
Transfer-encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Server: nginx
{
  "access_token": "5a1cbc26e4b0532d095e72a03b7338a42b2921b3ce0ea5195306052c", 
  "expires_in": 3600, 
  "refresh_token": "5a1cbc26e4b0532d095e72a03f8869a03f7d8a58bd605102820c67ad"
}

Comment: the response does not have the “"token_type": "Bearer" which is mentioned in the [Google Docs](https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/oauth2?oauth=code#implement_your_oauth_server) it that ok？

Comment: I added "token_type: Bearer" to the entity-body and added "Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8" to the header. I still get the error ```HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Transfer-encoding: chunked
Server: nginx
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-control: no-store
Date: Sat, 26 Jan 2019 06:53:07 GMT
Content-type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
{
  "token_type": "Bearer", 
  "access_token": "5a1cbc26e4b0532d095e72a06f7166e06efd9a352fde707b6ac485ea", 
  "expires_in": 3600, 
  "refresh_token": "5a1cbc26e4b0532d095e72a0156471a8ac463788b775b53e684d78b9"
}```

Comment: @NickFelker  this problem has plagued me for a long time. Can you give me more advice?

Comment: It appears to be an issue with your OAuth implementation, which does make it hard to debug. Your response appears to be correct, but I don't know enough about the internal working.s